# File not being created in root directory

Tags: java, file, exception, directory

I am getting this error

`Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Access is denied
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(Unknown Source)`

here is the code, I get that exception after I hit the createNewFile line..

```
    `


    //ELSE Creating the new file
    String fileName =  userName + ".usr";
    File f = new File("C:/", fileName);
    f.createNewFile(); }`
```

Comment: run the code as administrator.(e.g. open command prompt by right click an run as admin)

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the file yourself. Most new windows os prevent writing to root c without elevated permissions. If you cant create it manually without special permissions same goes to your code.

Comment: ahh, I realize that now. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

`createNewFile()` method throws `IOException`. You should handle the exception.

Comment: That is exactly what OP said. It doesn't seem to try to answer the question though.